# create table with values using js

Tags: javascript

I want to create table using javascript and fill it with data. So I decided to use `prompt` method and loop `while`.

But when I try to load page I always get two error message in google chrome developer tools
[image]

Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onStart() {
        var list = new Array();
        var headers = new Array("Имя","Отчество","Фамилия","Дата рождения");
        var i = -1;
        while(true) {
            var a = prompt("Имя","noname");
            var b = prompt("Отчество","nomiddlename");
            var c = prompt("Фамилия","nosurname");
            var d = prompt("Дата рождения!",0);
            if (confirm("Уверены что хотите добавить студента?")) {
                i++;
                list[i] = a + "-" + b + "-" + c + "-" + d;
            }else{ break; };
        }
        tab = "<table>";
        for(j = 0; j<headers.length;j++) {
            tab += "<th>" + headers[j] + "</th>";
        for(var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            var params = list[i].split('-');
            tab += "<tr>";
            for(k = 0; k < params.length;k++) {
                tab +="<td>" + params[k] + "</td>";
            }
            tab +="</tr>";
        }
        tab +="</table>";
        document.write(tab);
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad = "onStart()">
</body>
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loops seem to be mis-indented and not closed properly

```
for(j = 0; j<headers.length;j++) {
        tab += "<th>" + headers[j] + "</th>";
    for(var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        var params = list[i].split('-');
        tab += "<tr>";
        for(k = 0; k < params.length;k++) {
            tab +="<td>" + params[k] + "</td>";
        }
        tab +="</tr>";
    }
```

Should be

```
for(j = 0; j<headers.length;j++) {
    tab += "<th>" + headers[j] + "</th>";
}
for(var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
    var params = list[i].split('-');
    tab += "<tr>";
    for(k = 0; k < params.length;k++) {
        tab +="<td>" + params[k] + "</td>";
    }
    tab +="</tr>";
}
```

Not directly related to your question, but you have a few other common javascript errors.
By not declaring variables with var, you are unintentionally creating global variables.  While this probably isn't a huge issue on your page, but it is bad practice.

In addition, you should wrap your `<th>` tags you are appending inside of a `<tr>`, as the only "valid" element within a `<table>` is a `<tr>` (technically its tbody, thead, and tfoot, of which the only valid children is `<tr>`).

Comment: My guess is that this is supposed to be two independent loops, not nested loops.

Comment: @aepheus you are probably right, I'll update the answer to reflect that, and the fact that adding `<th>` to a `<table>` element is also incorrect

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing } on your first loop:

```
for(j = 0; j<headers.length;j++) {

  tab += "<th>" + headers[j] + "</th>";
```

**}**

I would go to guess he is trying to loop thru headers, followed by columns, then close the table. Not loop thru headers, and for each header add all rows. And, certainly not loop thru headers and for each header loop through all rows and close and write the table.

Answer (score 0):

In your code onStart(){} method is not closed properly. Add one more "**}**" in front of the below code

```
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: I don't think it is the function he didn't close, as that would make some strange behavior in those loops.

Comment: @aepheus It is just quick solution to him.

Comment: Quick solution or not, I'm sure he is hoping for the correct output.